# Discerning Difference Between Discrete Random Variable Distributions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Okay, so I have a few example that would follow Discrete random variable distributions, but I am having a hard time understanding when to use which distribution.

> $1.$ You are in possession of a fake ID that gets
>   you into a club $20%$ percent  of the time. Each attempt
>   is independent of other attempts. Let
>   $F$ denote the number of clubs that you fail to
>   get into prior to getting into $2$ clubs. How is
>   $F$ distributed?
>
> $2.$ A bowl contains $6$ green, $5$ yellow, $4$ orange, $3$
>   red, $2$ blue, and $1$ brown skittles. Randomly
>   grab five skittles from the bowl. Let $R$ denote
>   the number of red skittles you grab. How is $R$
>   distributed?
>
> $3.$ Play $50$ rounds of roulette always betting on
>   black. Let $L$ denote the number of times you
>   lose. A roulette table has $18$ black spaces, $18$
>   red spaces, and $2$ green spaces. All $38$ spaces
>   have equal size. You win if a ball lands on a
>   black space. You lose if the ball lands on a
>   red or green space. How is $L$ distributed?
>
> $4.$ A family is going to make babies until they
>   have three girls. Let $T$ denote the total
>   number of children in the family. How is $T$
>   distributed?

My attempts: $1.$ Negative Binomial (Because we are looking for $2$ successes and want to know number of trials until then.)

$2.$ I am fairly certain this is a hypergeometric distribution. (My question mainly pertains to the other distributions)

$3.$ I believe that this distribution is a regular binomial distribution (Looking for $k$ successes)

$4.$ I am unsure on this one, I lean towards Negative Binomial as well, but am not sure. It seems similar to $1.$ to me.

I am struggling to understand when a certain distribution applies and when it doesn't. For example, numbers $1.$, $3.$, and $4.$ all seem to be very close to me.

Comment: PS: In addition to the family of distributions, you should also identify the relevant paramters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $1.$ You are in possession of a fake ID that gets you into a club $20%$ percent  of the time. Each attempt is independent of other attempts. Let $F$ denote the number of clubs that you fail to get into prior to getting into $2$ clubs. How is $F$ distributed?

$F$ is the count for "successes" before the second "failure" in an indefinite sequence of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials with given "success" rate.  (Note: a "success" here is "not getting into the club".† )

This is indeed a *negative binomial distribution* with parameters $r=2,$ and $p=0.80$.

> $2.$ A bowl contains $6$ green, $5$ yellow, $4$ orange, $3$ red, $2$ blue, and $1$ brown skittles. Randomly grab five skittles from the bowl. Let $R$ denote
>   the number of red skittles you grab. How is $R$ distributed?

$R$ is the count of successes selected in a sample of known size selected from a population of known size containing a known amount of successes.

This is indeed a *hypergeometric distribution* whith parameters of $N=16$, $K=3$, and $n=5$.

> $3.$ Play $50$ rounds of roulette always betting on black. Let $L$ denote the number of times you lose. A roulette table has $18$ black spaces, $18$ red spaces, and $2$ green spaces. All $38$ spaces have equal size. You win if a ball lands on a black space. You lose if the ball lands on a red or green space. How is $L$ distributed?

$L$ is the count of "successes" (a loss) in a definite sequence of iid Bernoulli trials with calculatable "success" rate.

This is indeed a *binomial distribution*. What are the parameters?

> $4.$ A family is going to make babies until they have three girls. Let $T$ denote the total number of children in the family. How is $T$ distributed?

$T$ is the count of *trials* until three "failures"† in an indefinite sequence of iid Bernouli trials with a "success" rate you have to assume.

Now $T{-}3$ has a negative binomial distribution, so $T$ itself has a *shifted negative binomial distribution*.

( Of course, some texts will call this a negative binomial and call that of $F$ the shifted distribution.   So it always pays to be clarify exactly what is being counted. )

---

† For centuries Mathematicians have been annoyed by the "success" and "failure" terminiology, but haven't come up with anything better because, *meh*.

Answer (score 0):

4.negative binomial

3.binomial

I think and

1.) is negative binomial.
As I remember for

2.)  you must specify the number of g,y,r,o,b

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the term "negative binomial" is used in two conflicting senses. It is sometimes taken to mean the distribution of the number of failures before a specified number of successes (so that it can be $0,1,2,3,\ldots$) and sometimes to mean the number of trials needed to get the specifited number of successes (so that it can be $r,r+1,r+2,r+3,\ldots$, where $r$ is that specified number). #1 and #4 have negative binomial distributions according to the first and second senses respectively.

#2 is hypergeometric and #3 is binomial.